# Reading CSV file in java by passing column names as key in maps

Tags: java, csv

The attached file is a CSV file.
Write a Java program to read data from this file and populate each service in separate maps and print it.

```
CSV File
--------
CompanyName location  foundedby   profit noofyears

HCL          chennai  shivnadar   3.2     8

XYZ           chennai   XCV       9       10
```

In this how to pass the column names as key in two separate maps (one map for `HCL` and another map for `XYZ`)

Each row has separate mapping.

My code is

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class ReadServicesExercise {   
    public static void main(String[] args) {   
        String file = "D://ReadCsv.csv";   
        try{   
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));   
            Map<Integer,String> values = new HashMap<Integer,String>();   
            String line = "";   
            StringTokenizer tokens = null;   
            int lineNo = 0;   
            int tokenNo = 0;   
            //reading the csv file line by line   
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {   
                //increment the lineNo after every line is being read   
                lineNo++;   
                System.out.println("Reading Line No. : "+lineNo);   
                tokens = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");   
                while (tokens.hasMoreTokens()) {   
                    //increment the token no!   
                    tokenNo++;   
                    //Print csv values   
                    System.out.print(tokens.nextToken() + "  ");   
                    //Need to write the values to the hashmap   
                    values.put(arg0, arg1);   
                }   
                 System.out.println();   
                 //reset token number   
                 tokenNo = 0;   
            }   

         }
        catch(Exception ex){   
            System.err.println("CSV file not found : " + ex);   
        }   
    }   
}
```

But it prints every line, but I want the first line column name to be passed as key and correspondingly values should display for each company name.

Comment: I would advise to use a library for parsing csv (like supercsv), as you could also have quotes and escape tokes (RFC-4180).

Comment: It's kind of harf to understand for me what exactly are you trying to achieve and what is your program doing now. This piece of code you posted here does not compile beacuse of the line: values.put(arg0, arg1); What are the arg0 and arg1? Second thing is that your CSV is delimited with whitespaces but you are tokenizeing by commas.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using maps within a map. Create maps corressponding to each row, with column name as key and cell values as values. Now the parent map will contain a unique row value as key, say Company name, and maps as the value.

While retriving, 1st retrive the row map using the unique key and then out of that map, use he column name as key to get values.

Row maps: Map(String, String)

Parent map: Map(String, Map)

Comment: I don't think your answer illustrates what you mean in a good way. Usually when the question contains some code fragment it is a good idea to build upon that in the answer and explain it alongside of code.